# Create a CGPDFDocument from a byte array

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, arrays, cgpdfdocument

In MonoTouch I am looking to create a `CGPDFDocument` from a byte array transferred back text encoded from a web service. However MonoTouch does not seem to support creation from anything other than a local file or downloaded from a URL.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to p/invoke into [CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) to create your own instance of a `CGPDFDocument`. It should not be too complex since [CGDataProvider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html) already available in MonoTouch.

OTOH receiving an array (from a web service) can consume a lot of memory (unless you're 100% sure about their small size). E.g. string to byte conversion, it must all fit in memory...

TO be safe you might want to serialize the array (or better stream it directly if possible) to a local (temporary/cache) file first (to avoid another in-memory copy for the `GCPDFDocument` instance) and then call the existing `CGPDFDocument.FromFile` API.

**UPDATE**: MonoTouch 5.3.3+ will provide new constructor for `GCPDFDocument` that accept a `CGDataProvider`. In the mean time you can use the following code.

```
[DllImport (Constants.CoreGraphicsLibrary)]
extern static IntPtr CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider (IntPtr provider);

static GCPDFDocument FromArray (byte[] array)
{
    using (var dp = new CGDataProvider (array, 0, array.Length) {
        return new CGPDFDocument (CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider (dp.Handle));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent many thanks - in fact I recently discovered that it is very easy to load a PDF byte array directly into a UIWebView